# insert data from multiple tables

Tags: asp.net, join, insert, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table named sec_user with columns named

```
[track_id]    [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[submit_don]  [datetime] NULL,
[page_title]  [varchar](100) NULL,
[url]         [varchar](500) NULL,
[emp_details] [varchar](5000) NULL,
[ip]          [varchar](20) NULL,
[referer_url] [varchar](500) NULL,
[user_id]     [int] NULL,
[profile_id]  [int] NULL,
```

here column named [user_id] and [profile_id] has to inserted from employee_tbl and profile_tbl rest of the columns has to be inserted by normal insert statement.

**here user_id is common in both tables employee_tbl and profile_tbl**. So I want to insert record for a specific user_id**

Comment: I think you need to describe a bit more in detail what you need, for example how you're supposed to locate which user_id and person_id to insert. Inserting a random user_id and profile_id from those tables probably won't make anyone happier.

Answer (score 1):

Just prefix the select statement that gets you the data with insert tablename.
e.g
If you had Customers and Orders and you wanted a ActiveCustomerOrders table

```
Insert ActiveCustomerOrders(CustomerName,OrderID,Order_Date,SomeOtherColumn) 
Select c.CustomerName,o.OrderID, o.OrderDate, 'SomeValue'  From Customers c
Inner Join Orders o On o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
Where O.Fulfilled = 0
```

Comment: but what about the rest of the columns that do not not have related table so I have to insert records in those columns too along with this.

Comment: Um, hold on. I'll beef up the answer, but you'll be slapping yourself

Comment: Oh! Thanks it worked Now I am able to insert records manually as well as using select statement with Insert too. Actually I was bit puzzled on how to add values of those columns that are no where in any table. But now I have successfully did that. Thanks!